# Non-deterministic NPE thrown by Websphere liberty in com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader

Tags: spring, classloader, websphere-liberty

Very often I'm getting following exception when starting multiple WARs with applications based on Spring Boot:

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.foo.SomeService]: Factory method 'someService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someBean' defined in com.foo.SomeJavaConfig: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2487)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:994)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6566)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.getClassSpecificProtectionDomainPrivileged(AppClassLoader.java:367)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.access$000(AppClassLoader.java:64)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader$2.run(AppClassLoader.java:351)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader$2.run(AppClassLoader.java:348)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.getClassSpecificProtectionDomain(AppClassLoader.java:348)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:325)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:271)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ParentLastClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:80)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:443)
at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:50)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:431)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
... 76 common frames omitted
```

It is non-deteministic - it happens that all WARs are starting well.
Issue is reproducible on WLP ver: 18.0.0.3 and 19.0.0.3 (didn't tested on other).
Spring version 4.3.17.RELEASE
For me it looks like a bug but perhaps someone has already fix for it and could help.

Comment: I agree this does look like a bug. At least in the version of Liberty you are using. Since it's a bug I would recommend raising a github issue on OpenLiberty or IBM support ticket if you have WAS Liberty support.

Comment: Issue on github created - [link](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/7345)

Answer (score 0):

What Java level are you using to run this scenario?  It is a possibility that this problem relates to Java and not Liberty which is why I ask.  We have seen some issues with non deterministic NullPointerExceptions in some levels of Java that were fixed in later Java levels.

There have been a lot of changes in the AppClassLoader from 18.0.0.3 to 19.0.0.3, but the stack you provided is from the 18.0.0.3 level of code which hadn't changed in a long time so it looks like it isn't a new problem.  If it is a Liberty problem, opening an issue on the OpenLiberty github would be appropriate.  You will likely need to reproduce the problem with trace though in order for IBM to debug it more.  The trace spec I would recommend is com.ibm.ws.classloading.*=finest:com.ibm.ws.artifact.*=finest

Comment: This should also be put into the trace spec:
com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.*=finest